# How to select data based on special condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Says I have `TABLE Audit` with `COLUMN ID, STATUS, TIME` and sample data as below:

```
1. {ID = 1, STATUS = 'APPROVE', TIME = '2015-02-01'}
2. {ID = 1, STATUS = 'DECLINE', TIME = '2014-12-01'}
3. {ID = 1, STATUS = 'CLOSED', TIME = '2015-11-01'}
4. {ID = 2, STATUS = 'APPROVE', TIME = '2015-02-01'}
5. {ID = 3, STATUS = 'DECLINE', TIME = '2015-10-01'}
6. {ID = 4, STATUS = 'CLOSED', TIME = '2015-02-01'}
```

There's a condition: If `status='approve'` then ignore `status='decline'` else select everything.

May I know how to construct a query so that I will get only records : 1,3,4,5,6?

My current way is first retrieve all data with `status='approve' and 'closed'` and store them into `temptable`, then store data that is `status = 'decline' and ID not in @temptable` into `@temptable`. Then eventually `select * from @temptable`.

I'm wondering if there's any other way to handle such situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *
 ,[dec] = COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'DECLINE' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
 ,[app] = COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'APPROVE' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
FROM #Audit
)
SELECT ID, STATUS, [TIME]
FROM cte
WHERE NOT ([dec] >= 1 AND [app] >= 1 AND [STATUS] = 'DECLINE');
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402942)**</kbd>

Your column `TIME` can be misleading especially when it holds date only :)

Answer (score 2):

THe idea it is to get all the ones that have been approved and for those skip the declined ones.
I couldn't try right now, but it should work:

```
;WITH App (ID, app) AS
    (SELECT ID, COUNT(1) FROM #Audit WHERE STATUS = 'APPROVE' GROUP BY ID UNION
    SELECT ID, 0 FROM #Audit WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM #Audit WHERE STATUS = 'APPROVE')  GROUP BY ID )
SELECT *, ISNULL(App.app, 0) 
FROM #Audit LEFT OUTER JOIN App ON #Audit.ID = App.ID
WHERE ISNULL(App.app, 0) = 0 OR (App.app = 1 AND #audit.status != 'DECLINE')
```

Comment: @lad2025 thanks, most of all because i didn't know of the capability of data.stackexchange query engine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from audit a1
where not exists(
    select * from audit a2 
    where a2.status='approve' and a1.status='decline' and a2.id=a1.id
)
```

Comment: select 1 from audit a2 can be more efficient under some circuntencies (lots of rows). I rather like this answer. +1

Comment: IMO there is absolutely no performance difference between `select 1` and `select *` in this context - SQL server doesn't process/return all columns anyway.

Comment: I am just mentioning it because it can improve performance in some context and select top 1 is usually prefered. With an index on id with a where clause on status=approve, select 1 only do an index seek. select * will also be followed by a key lookup.

Comment: either way, you solution seems to be the most efficient with a properly design table and index.